# post Ajax does not call method controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller in MVC with a post method:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult GuardarPedido(clsEnrutaModel pedido)
 {
    try
    {                
        clsEnrutaBLL bll = new clsEnrutaBLL();                
        bll.Save(pedido);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        GENException.Write(ex, "EnrutaController.GuardarPedido");
        return Json(new { success = false, message = string.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message) });
    }
    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Pedido Guardado Correctamente." });
}
```

And in the view I have a Ajax call:

```
var pedido = {
            Fol_enr: $("#txtFolio").val(),
            Numcte_enr: { 
                Num_cte: "9000",
                Nom_cte: "",
                Rfc_cte: "",
                Direccion: {
                    Dir: $("#txtDireccion").val()
                }
            },
            Fecreg_enr: FormatoFechaReg(),
            Prc_enr: $("#txtPrecio").val(),
            Eco_enr: {
                Cve_uni: $("#idEco").val()
            },
            Ruta_enr: {
                Cve_rut: ""
            },
            Edovta_enr: "",
            Ltssur_enr: $("#txtLitros").val(),
            Ubicte_enr: "",
            Fecate_enr: FormatoFechaCompleto(),
            Edoreg_enr: "N",
            Totvta_enr: $("#txtTotal").val(),
            Obser_enr: "",
            Faccal_enr: "31",
            Tippgo_enr: 1,
            Com_enr: "",
            Golpe_enr: $("#txtGolpe").val(),
            Mens_enr: "",
            RecCel_enr: 0
        };

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Enruta/GuardarPedido", 
            data: JSON.stringify(pedido),
            contentType: "application/json",
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.message);
                if (data.success) {
                    $("#createForm").dialog(opt).dialog("close");
                    Consultar();
                }  
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }
        });
```

When a execute the app, codes go fine before ajax call, ajax call does not execute the eero is the next:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

What is wrong?

Comment: one thing is your `datatype: "html"` should probably be `datatype: "json"`

Comment: don't use stringify, try like : ``data: pedido``

Comment: also, I don't _think_ it matters but I would change `ActionResult` to `JsonResult` because you are returning Json.

Comment: @zgood that does not matter

Comment: put a break point in action and see what is happening

Comment: Code of the method controller is not executed @Ehsan Sajjad

Comment: @DanielVorph is it in a different Area?

Comment: @zgood ajax call is in a partial view

Comment: Make sure the data you are passing matches your model - If necessary try to test it with a model that has 1 or 2 properties then test it with nested objects. And use "application/json; charset=utf-8" as contentType

Comment: @Zaki Thanks for the advice, the problem was that data didn't match with the model